# Replace all images on page with their src properties

Tags: javascript, image, src, bookmarklet

I need to create a bookmarklet replacing all on-site images with strings that'd be src URLs of these images. I am not JS guy, so I can show my non-valid code to give an impression of what I want.

it's something like this:

```
var tags = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
for (var i = 0; i < tags.length; i++) { 
var image = tags[i].getAttribute("src");
tags[i].innerHTML = image; }
```

I know it should be extremely easy to do, but I couldn't find any working solution.

Comment: Do you want to get the source of `img` and replace it with string?

Comment: I want that all images on current site would turn into SRC of those images (that images'd be replaced by text - their source URLs right on page)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I’d suggest:

```
// retrieve all <img> elements in the document,
// using document.querySelector(); then iterate
// over that NodeList using
// NodeList.prototype.forEach():
document.querySelectorAll('img').forEach(

  // 'el' is a reference to the current element of
  // of the NodeList of elements; and here we use
  // Node.replaceWith() to replace the current ('el')
  // Node with a textNode, with the node-value set to
  // the src of the element:
  (el) => el.replaceWith(document.createTextNode(el.src))
);
```

```js
// retrieve all <img> elements in the document,
// using document.querySelector(); then iterate
// over that NodeList using
// NodeList.prototype.forEach():
document.querySelectorAll('img').forEach(

  // 'el' is a reference to the current element of
  // of the NodeList of elements; and here we use
  // Node.replaceWith() to replace the current ('el')
  // Node with a textNode, with the node-value set to
  // the src of the element:
  (el) => el.replaceWith(document.createTextNode(el.src))
);
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/wa24z.jpg"></li>
  <li><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/jS9JB.jpg"></li>
  <li><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/ifMfn.jpg"></li>
  <li><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/rlEus.jpg"></li>
  <li><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/sRoGY.jpg"></li>
  <li><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/0dsoZ.jpg"></li>
  <li><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/GO9Tx.jpg"></li>
</ul>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/ad8soxyv/3).

The above, with its usage of ES6 features (`let`, `childNode.replaceWith()` and Arrow functions) will not work in browsers that don't implement ES6; the following is an alternative using ES5 which may be more reliable:

```js
function naiveReplaceWith(originalNode, replacementNode) {

  // here we navigate from the originalNode (the node to be replaced)
  originalNode
    // to its parentNode:
    .parentNode
    // and call parentNode.replaceChild:
    .replaceChild(
      // supplying the replacement-node as the first argument:
      replacementNode,
      // and the original node as the second:
      originalNode);
}

// here we use Array.prototype.slice(), along with Function.prototype.call,
// to allow us to apply the Array.prototype.forEach() to the Array-like
// NodeList returned by document.querySelectorAll():
Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('img')).forEach(function(el) {
  // using the anonoymous function on each of the elements in the Array of elements:
  naiveReplaceWith(el, document.createTextNode(el.src));
});
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/wa24z.jpg"></li>
  <li><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/jS9JB.jpg"></li>
  <li><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/ifMfn.jpg"></li>
  <li><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/rlEus.jpg"></li>
  <li><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/sRoGY.jpg"></li>
  <li><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/0dsoZ.jpg"></li>
  <li><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/GO9Tx.jpg"></li>
</ul>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/ad8soxyv/6/).

If you wanted to have the `src` text as a clickable link, so that the user could follow the link to the source image:

```js
// a named function that takes a couple of arguments,
// the URL to be the href of the created element, and
// the String which will be the text-content of the
// created elemeent:
let anchorCreate = (href, text) => {

  // creating an <a> element:
  let a = document.createElement('a');

  // setting the href property:
  a.href = href;

  // setting the textContent property; if there is
  // no supplied text then the textContent will be
  // set to the href:
  a.textContent = text || href;

  return a;
}
// retrieve all <img> elements in the document,
// using document.querySelector(); then iterate
// over that NodeList using
// NodeList.prototype.forEach():
document.querySelectorAll('img').forEach(

  // here we replace the current element ('el') with
  // the content returned from the function:
  (el) => el.replaceWith(anchorCreate(el.src))

);
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/wa24z.jpg"></li>
  <li><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/jS9JB.jpg"></li>
  <li><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/ifMfn.jpg"></li>
  <li><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/rlEus.jpg"></li>
  <li><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/sRoGY.jpg"></li>
  <li><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/0dsoZ.jpg"></li>
  <li><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/GO9Tx.jpg"></li>
</ul>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/ad8soxyv/4).

References:

- [`Array.prototype.slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice).
- [Arrow Functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).
- [`ChildNode.replaceWith()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/replaceWith).
- [`document.createElement()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement).
- [`document.createTextNode()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createTextNode).
- [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll).
- [`Function.prototype.call()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is this solution optimized to work as a bookmarklet? I tried to use it with Opera Mobile without any result.

Comment: It's not optimised in any way whatsoever, my guess is that Opera Mobile may not be compliant with ES6, in which case try: https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/ad8soxyv/2/

Comment: Should I use this code "as is" adding "javascript:" before it? If yes, it's still no luck. I tried both Safari Mobile and opera mobile. Maybe there is no "mobile solution" at all?

Comment: All of the demos run for me, in Safari on iOS 11.4.1; Opera Mobile I have no knowledge of but I’d argue its usage is low enough that it’s possibly irrelevant. Also, if by ‘Opera Mobile’ you mean ‘Opera Mini,’ then it’s rendered server side which precludes, or at least complicates, most JavaScript interaction so far as I understand.

Answer (score 1):

You can probably set `display:none` to all the images and create text node with the `src` attribute:

```js
var tags = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
for (var i = 0; i < tags.length; i++) { 
var image = tags[i].getAttribute("src");
  tags[i].style.display = 'none';
  var el = document.createTextNode(image);
  document.getElementById('container').appendChild(el);
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <img src="/image1"/>
  <img src="/image2"/>
  <img src="/image3"/>
  <img src="/image4"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try this. this works fine and uses `pure js` (without any library):

```js
document.querySelectorAll("img").forEach((i)=>{
  i.insertAdjacentElement("afterend", ((sc)=>{sc.classList.add("replaced-text");  sc.innerHTML=i.src; return sc;})(document.createElement("span")));
  i.parentNode.removeChild(i);
});
```

```css
.replaced-text{
  display: block;
  color: #300;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="https://lorempixel.com/50/50/nature/1" alt=""/>
  <img src="https://lorempixel.com/50/50/nature/2" alt=""/>
  <img src="https://lorempixel.com/50/50/nature/3" alt=""/>
  <img src="https://lorempixel.com/50/50/nature/4" alt=""/>
  <img src="https://lorempixel.com/50/50/nature/5" alt=""/>
  <img src="https://lorempixel.com/50/50/nature/6" alt=""/>
</div>
```